# Array Object Value Not Displaying

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I'm trying to cleanse some data and place an array of objects inside of an object.  Here's my array of objects.

careerStats:

```
[
  {
    gp: '35',
    gs: '34',
    mpg: '33.2',
    fg: '.515',
    tp: '1.5',
    ft: '1.4',
    rpg: '0.5',
    apg: '0.7',
    bpg: '.692',
    spg: '0.7',
    ppg: '3.6'
  },
  {
    gp: '22',
    gs: '22',
    mpg: '36.7',
    fg: '.504',
    tp: '5.5',
    ft: '2.4',
    rpg: '1.7',
    apg: '2.0',
    bpg: '.822',
    spg: '1.5',
    ppg: '6.5'
  },
  {
    gp: '57',
    gs: '56',
    mpg: '34.6',
    fg: '.509',
    tp: '3.1',
    ft: '1.8',
    rpg: '1.0',
    apg: '1.2',
    bpg: '.775',
    spg: '1.0',
    ppg: '4.7'
  }
]
```

And here's how I'm placing the careerStats array of objects inside of a player array.

player:

```
player.push(
    {
        name: "",
        image: "",
        position: "",
        description: "",
        dob: "",
        hometown: "",
        country: "",
        height_feet: "",
        height_inches: "",
        weight: "",
        season: careerStats
    });
```

This does not return any sort of error; however, when I log the player to the console here's what displays:

```
[
  {
    name: '',
    image: '',
    position: '',
    description: '',
    dob: '',
    hometown: '',
    country: '',
    height_feet: '',
    height_inches: '',
    weight: '',
    season: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  }
]
```

Since I know the data is fine when it's in the careerStats array, this leads me to two questions:

1. Am I doing something incorrectly to receive this output as [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ]?
   **ANSWER**: Resolved by changing to console.log(JSON.stringify(player))
2. If this is the expected output and the data is indeed there, how can I write this to a JSON file where the data displays instead of "[object Object]"?

   ```
       JSON.stringify(player);
       fs.appendFile('myjsonfile.json', player, function (err) {
           if (err) throw err;
           console.log('Saved!');
       });
   ```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: You can click on the objects in the console to expand them

Comment: Try `console.log(JSON.stringify(player))` you should see what you expect.

Comment: `console.log` will only recurse into an array or object so many levels before it prints generic type strings. This is so you can print complex objects with deep levels of nested data without it taking up thousands of lines when all you wanted was to view some of the top-level fields.

Comment: @Barmar - thank you for the information, I did not know he limits to console.log!

Comment: @Abion47 - same to you, I learned something valuable this morning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write to a JSON file in Node then perhaps use node filesystem

1. Convert the object to JSON using [JSON.stringify()](https://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/json/stringify)

   ```
   const fs = require('fs'); // Load in filesystem
   const playerJSON = JSON.stringify(player);
   ```
2. Create JSON file using [fs.writeFileSync()](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options) - The below will create a JSON file in your directory called `player.json` with player data stored as JSON

   ```
   fs.writeFileSync('player.json', playerJSON);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

`console.log()` will only show up to 2 levels of your object's structure, anything else will be "collapsed" like that.

You could use [`console.dir()`](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_dir_obj_options):

```
console.dir(player, { depth: null });
```

Or [`util.inspect`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options):

```
const util = require('util')

console.log(util.inspect(player, { depth: null });
```

Or [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(player, null, 2));
```

However, note `JSON.stringify()` has some limitations like not being able to handle circular references or not displaying functions at all.

I would go for `console.dir()`, as it already uses `util.inspect` internally, as stated in the docs:

> Uses `util.inspect()` on `obj` and prints the resulting string to `stdout`. j.